# Fit website in bounding box with AbcPDF

Tags: pdf-generation, abcpdf

I can't seem to fit a webpage that has a longer height inside my bounding box below.  When the BrowserWidth is smaller, that webpage overflows the page, but when it's larger then the bounding box it fits fine.

```
public abstract class HtmlToPdfModel : IPdfModel
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public int PageWidth { get; set; } // 850 (in pixels)
        public int PageHeight { get; set; } // 844 (in pixels)
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public virtual byte[] GetStream()
        {
            using (var doc = new Doc())
            {
                var w = doc.MediaBox.Width;
                var h = doc.MediaBox.Height;
                var l = doc.MediaBox.Left;
                var b = doc.MediaBox.Bottom;

                doc.Transform.Rotate(90, l, b);
                doc.Transform.Translate(w, 0);
                doc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheEnabled = false;
                doc.Rect.Width = h; // 792
                doc.Rect.Height = w; // 612

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string.Format("{0}&r={1}", Url, new Random().Next(1, 100000))))
                {
                    var ratio = GetViewPortRatio((int)doc.Rect.Width, (int)doc.Rect.Height, PageWidth, PageHeight);

                    doc.HtmlOptions.BrowserWidth = (int)(doc.Rect.Width * ratio);
                    doc.AddImageUrl(Url);
                }

                doc.SetInfo(doc.GetInfoInt(doc.Root, "Pages"), "/Rotate", "90");

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    doc.Save(ms);
                    if (ms.CanSeek)
                    {
                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }
                    return ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it with the following.

```
using (var doc = new Doc())
            {
                var w = doc.MediaBox.Width;
                var h = doc.MediaBox.Height;
                var l = doc.MediaBox.Left;
                var b = doc.MediaBox.Bottom;

                doc.Transform.Rotate(90, l, b);
                doc.Transform.Translate(w, 0);
                doc.HtmlOptions.PageCacheEnabled = false;
                doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
                doc.Rect.Width = h;
                doc.Rect.Height = w;
                //doc.Rendering.DotsPerInch = 92;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string.Format("{0}&r={1}", Url, new Random().Next(1, 100000))))
                {
                    var actualWidth = PageWidth / .75f;
                    var dimensionsScale = GetViewPortScale(PageHeight, PageWidth);

                    doc.HtmlOptions.BrowserWidth = Convert.ToInt32(actualWidth * dimensionsScale);

                    doc.AddImageUrl(Url);
                }

                doc.SetInfo(doc.GetInfoInt(doc.Root, "Pages"), "/Rotate", "90");

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    doc.Save(ms);
                    if (ms.CanSeek)
                    {
                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }
                    return ms.GetBuffer();
                }
            }


       private float GetViewPortScale(float currentDimension, float dimension)
    {
        return (currentDimension / dimension);
    }
```

Comment: in our project also we facing same issue. abcpdf not showing full tabular data..because our table having more than 20 columns so it doesn't fit on the screen,instead of this it displays scrollbar

Comment: how can i display all tabular data in abcpdf.if you have any idea ? struggling long time..